# Path3d Offset from GlobalPosition

Tags: godot, 3d-meshes, path

my path3d node is several meters away from the global position.My transform are not changed from their base setting.
[image: Picture]
[image: TopDown]
[image: SideWay]
Code:

```
 [Export]
 Node3D Start { get; set; }
 [Export]
 Node3D End { get; set; }
 [Export]
 float LineRadius = 0.1f;
 [Export]
 int LineResolution = 8;
 [Export]
 CsgPolygon3D Polygon3D;
 int ArrayLenght;
 [Export]
 Path3D LinePath;
 bool Update;
 [Export]
 bool test;
 public override void _Ready()//use pathfollow to over the player over the path:) //end and start point get more twisted the heavier the player is
 {
     base._Ready();
     
     var count = LinePath.Curve.PointCount;
     if(Start != null)
     {
         LinePath.Curve.SetPointPosition(0, Start.GlobalPosition); 
         GD.Print("Setting First Point to Point 1 Position");
     }
     if(End != null)
     {
         LinePath.Curve.SetPointPosition(count-1, End.GlobalPosition);
         GD.Print("Setting the Last point to Point 2 Position");
     }
     MeshUpdate();
     
 }
 public override void _Process(double delta)
 {
     base._Process(delta);
     if (Update == true)
     {
         MeshUpdate();
         Update= false;
     }

     if (test == true)
     {
         Update = true;
         test = false;
     }
 }
 public void MeshUpdate()
 {
     var cirle = new Vector2[LineResolution];
     
     for (int i = 0; i < LineResolution; i++)//circle is empty
     {
         float X = LineRadius * Mathf.Sin((Mathf.Pi * 2 * i) / LineResolution);
         float Y = LineRadius * Mathf.Cos((Mathf.Pi * 2 * i) / LineResolution);
         Vector2 coords = new Vector2(X, Y);
         cirle[i] = coords;
     
     }
     Polygon3D.Polygon = cirle;
     if(Start!=null && End != null)
     {
         UpdateOrientation();
     }
 }
 public void OnPathChanged()
 {
     Update = true;
 }
 public void UpdateOrientation()
 {
     Vector3 direction=Start.GlobalPosition- End.GlobalPosition;
     Vector3 linePosition = Start.GlobalPosition + (direction / 2);
     direction = direction.Normalized();
     Basis LineBasis = GlobalBasis;
     LineBasis.Z = direction;
     LineBasis.Y = direction.Cross(LineBasis.X);
     LineBasis.X = direction.Cross(LineBasis.Y);
     GlobalBasis = LineBasis;
     
     
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the curve3d got their position from another scene which is why it presented itself in another position.There is no way to fix this as this is just visual and does not effect the game.
if it bothers you,remove the tool line.